# Query Optimisation - Collating result from one to many relationship table efficiently in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I am trying to combine one-to-many table. I want to display the variants for one item together. This has to be done entirely in SQL.

Here is the sample Schema

```
CREATE TABLE ItemVariant (`item_id` int, `variant_id` int, `variant` varchar(55), `variant_order` int);
INSERT INTO ItemVariant (`variant_id`, `item_id`, `variant`, `variant_order`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'I1V1', 1),
    (2, 1, 'I1V2', 2),
    (3, 1, 'I1V3', 3),
    (4, 2, 'I2V1', 1)
;

CREATE TABLE Item (`item_id` int, `item` varchar(55));
INSERT INTO Item (`item_id`, `item`)
VALUES (1,'I1'), (2,'I2');
```

Here is a working query which gives me what is required. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b38/10)

```
SELECT Item.item, iv1.variant, iv2.variant, iv3.variant from Item
LEFT JOIN ItemVariant iv1 ON (Item.item_id = iv1.item_id and iv1.variant_order=1)
LEFT JOIN ItemVariant iv2 ON (Item.item_id = iv2.item_id and iv2.variant_order=2)
LEFT JOIN ItemVariant iv3 ON (Item.item_id = iv3.item_id and iv3.variant_order=3)
```

However, as you can see, I have to access `ItemVariant` table 3 times and hence, it is not efficient. I thought of using `group by` but I am unable to query inside the groups formed by `group by`.

Here is what I tried for group by. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b38/14)

```
SELECT 
*, 
case when variant_order=1 then variant end as variant1,
case when variant_order=2 then variant end as variant2,
case when variant_order=3 then variant end as variant3
from  ItemVariant
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: What proof is there that the original query is 'not efficient'? (Neither will necessarily be 'efficient' due to missing indices and non-sargable queries.)

Comment: I have a query with such a construct and it takes 40 minutes against production data! This is one of the primary suspect.

Comment: What indexes do `Item` and `ItemVariant` have? Also, does this question pertain to MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: If that the way you want to use your data (Pivoting the rows to columns..., leaving NULLs where no data exists), why isn't your table structured this way?

Comment: If you want to make sure that's the reason your query takes 40 minutes, get rid of it. Use a single (left) join, have the output "unpivoted", and see if that reduces your execution time to an acceptable duration. If not, start looking elsewhere

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't add irrelevant tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Item.item, 
       MAX(case when variant_order=1 then variant end) as variant1,
       MAX(case when variant_order=2 then variant end) as variant2,
       MAX(case when variant_order=3 then variant end) as variant3
from ItemVariant
LEFT JOIN Item ON Item.item_id = ItemVariant.item_id
GROUP BY Item.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  i.item,
        GROUP_CONCAT(v.variant
                     ORDER BY  v.variant_order
                     SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Variants
    FROM  Item AS i
    JOIN  ItemVariant as v  ON v.item_id = i.item_id
    GROUP BY  i.item;
```